# Only 613 commandments? Can't be!

Tags: mitzvah, vilna-gaon

In the [beginning of the sefer Ma'alos HaTorah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33865&st=&pgnum=31&hilite=), authored by the brother of the Vilna Gaon, the question is asked (on the Gemara at the end of Makkos) how the gemara can state that there are **only** 613 mitzvos.

Rav Avraham's difficulty is because it's clear from the Rishonim that there are more than just 613.

Rav Avraham quotes his brother, the Vilna Gaon, who poses 2 difficulties with the low count of 613. One is that if it were true, there would be only 3 mitzvos from Bereishis to Bo. The second is that if it were true, there would be entire parshiyos (not sidra's) without any mitzvos.

My question is: Does anyone else pose this question or address these issues?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is with each of those questions.

Comment: @DoubleAA I wasn't sure how to understand the Gra's difficulties. If you look in the book you'll see that they'e not explained further. I had a couple of possibilities but the one I think fits best with the way the question is presented is : How could it be that you have sections of the Torah that are not telling us what to DO, this is a world of action and the Torah is its' guide. (Or something to that effect).

Comment: @Gavriel, if that is the question, see the first Rashi in Chumash.

Comment: Your link gives an answer. Are you looking for others who agree or only for different answers?

Comment: If the question is: assuming that only mitzvos are meaningful, then given that we find so few mitzvos from breishis to bo, then those passages must not be meaningful. This cant be, so therefore meaningfulness must not be based on being counted as a mitzvah. If so, the numerous geonim and rishonim who counted the mitzvos, were wasting time. If this is the question, the answer is that mitzvos can be meaningful inasmuch as they impart defined structured obligations, whereas other passages, such as stories may impart divine lessons. These are not structured but are left to the reader to apply.

Comment: This idea that we can, and indeed must learn from the stories on the Chumash is mentioned by many rishonim including the Malamad Hatalmidim, Ramban, Rashba, and IIRC R. Avraham ben Harambam. Accordingly the Gra's question is answered; these passages can be meaninfull even without imparting mitzvos. Thus, the lack of mitzvos in those parshos doesnt impugn the approach of counting the mitzvos which implicitely attaches significance to mitzvos over non-mitzvos. This also answers the second question which really seems like more of an emotional extension of the first question.

Comment: @Yishai "Your link etc."- I'm looking for others who agree with the difficulty and for different answers. "If the question etc."- The Gra gives a different answer. "This idea etc."- The Gra obviously (from his many comments on Nach) agrees with your general point of learning from the stories but nevertheless was not satisfied by your answer (seemingly neither was the 1st Rashi in both his question and answer.)

Comment: Gavriel, only I got pinged in your comment even though part of it was addressed to @mevaqesh, so I am pinging him as well.

Comment: I think that is exactly the point of the first Rashi in Chumash - Torah should have been about Mitzvos, and the stories left out, put in something else, whatever (different possibilities are discussed on this Rashi), so Rashi is saying that the whole narrative from Bereishis until Bo teaches an important lesson about history.

Comment: @Gavriel obviously the Gra wouldn't agree (assuming he actually said that which he is quoted as saying)! The question was why none of the Geoneim and Rishonim, e.g. Rasag, Bahag, Ibn Gabirol, Chefetz Ben Yatzliach, Rambam, Ramban, Yereim, Smag, Smak, Chinuch, and Charedim who worked so hard to establish the number of mitzvos thought like the Gra, that the number doesn't matter. And in fact they didnt even feel the need to defend themselves against such an idea. Obviously they had a radically different understanding than the Gra about the role of mitzvos.

Comment: @Gavriel you therefore cant ask on an explanation of the Rishonim that the Gra must not agree; of course he doesnt agree-he cant agree!

Comment: @mevaqesh I think we might be understanding the Gra differently. He has a reason for the 613 count (it is a Gemara after all!) and they are different than other mitzvos. The Gra has no apparent disagreement with the Rishonim who make the count. In a sentence, according to him the 613 or "roots" and the other endless amount of mitzvos are "branches", "leaves", "fruit" etc. Take a look at the book I linked in the question.

Comment: @Yishai I hear what you're saying about the Rashi but I'm not totally convinced. There are a huge number of things we learn from creation to Adam to Noach to Avraham etc. in Bereishis. Why does he have to go to the claim of the nations of the world and Eretz Yisroel if his answer is simply "We learn lots of stuff that aren't mitzvos but are nevertheless important"? You know what I mean?... I'm not sure, I'll have to investigate this a bit. (I wish I owned a Chumash with meforshei Rahsi.)

Comment: @mevaqesh ...continued- The 613 absolutely matter according to the Gra. I might not fully understand why they matter according to the way the answer is explained in the book. However Rav Avraham makes that point and says that it doesn't matter for us at this point which exactly are the 613 and which or the other ones. I have always wondered, in any event, why the Rishonim put in all that work to establish which are the 613... why did THEY think it was so important? Did they say that anything not in the 613 are not mi'deoraysa?

Comment: @Gavriel we must be miscommunication. To recap: Rambam writes explicitly in shorsh Rishon to Sefer Hamitzvos that only the 613 are d'oraysa. I dont remember anyone disputing this explicitly. R. Avraham begins by attacking the traditional monei hamitzvos broadly for focusing on the count, and specifically for certain features of their listings. He then cites the Gra. The Gra is bothered by the sub-par status attributed to mitzvos implicit in the count and therefore claims that every dibbur has an equal (or nearly equal standing). He is therefore faced with the problem of the Gemara itself which

Comment: Emphasizes the count. He answers essentially that the count is very minor; pertaining only to which mitzvos are shorashim and which are anafim, but all are mitzvos. He adds that we have no way of knowing which the 613 are, and that it makes no difference:  ואין מן הצורך לדעת זאת כי בכל מצוה ובכל דיבור נכלל מדבורי התורה נכללו כל התורה וכל המצות...

Comment: Therein lies his dispute with all of his post-talmudic predecessors. He holds that the only difference between mitzvos and non-mitzvos is a technical practically irrelevant point (indeed there cant be a nafka mina for he himself didnt know what the 613 were, and seems to have felt that we couldnt figure it out). The rishonim obviously agreed with none of this. They agreed that passages in the Torah could be meaningfull, but that wouldnt give them the same status as mitzvos.

Comment: A technical correction, Rambam doesn't hold that only 613 are d'oraysa, he holds that d'rabanan isn't 613. He holds however that a temporary mitzva is fully binding, but not counted in 613.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Ralbag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gersonides) addresses the issue of number of mitzvot in his commentary to Exodus Chapter 12 in the Sixth Lesson. He points out the following:

- R. Simlai in [Makkot 23b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=25&daf=23b&format=pdf) expounds that there are 613 mitzvot – 248 positive commandments and 365 negative commandments.
- [Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) tried very hard to calculate the exact 613 mitzvot, and surpassed all his predecessors in this regard, but there are still many issues with what he did.
- The issues with Rambam's counting are not due to any flaw of Rambam's; rather the number 613 was not really precise, and R. Simlai didn't care because he wanted to make an exposition with the significance of the number 613.
- Therefore, when counting the mitzvot, we should ignore R. Simlai's statement, and only count based on the actual truth.
- Furthermore, even if R. Simlai was being precise, we don't have to contend with his number because if our analysis of the Talmud results in a higher count then it would simply be a dispute and we would reject R. Simlai as the minority view.

> ואולם הרב רבינו משה ז"ל נלחץ לחץ רב במנין המצוות כדי שיעלה בידו בכיוון
>   החשבון שזכר ר' שמלאי בסוף מכות במצוות עשה ובמצוות לא תעשה  שהם תרי"ג 
>   ובהם רמ"ח מצוות עשה כמנין אבריו של אדם  ושס"ה מצוות לא תעשה כמנין ימות
>   החמה  וכאשר חקרנו אנחנו בזה  ומצאנו כמה ספקות עצומות במנין המצוות שזכר
>   הרב לפי העיקרים שהשריש אשר אין ספק באמיתתם  עם ראותנו שכבר הפליג העיון
>   בזה על כל מי שקדמהו ממי שהגיעו אלינו דבריהם  להסכים המספרים האלו לפי
>   מה שאפשר   הנה התבאר לנו שלא היה זה מפני קיצור הרב למצוא האמת בזה  אבל
>   מפני היות באלו המספרים שזכר ר' שמלאי קצת קירוב  לא חשש בו ר' שמלאי בזה
>   הדרש  ולזה אמרנו שאין ראוי שילחצנו זה המספר הנזכר בזה המקום למצוות על
>   צד הדרש  ממנות המצוות על האופן שראוי שימנו לפי האמת  וזה  כי כמו
>   שיוציאו בדרש פסוק אחד מכוונתו  להוציא ממנו מוסר טוב  כמו שנתפרסם מהדרש
>   שאמרו רבותינו ז"ל על ויתד תהיה לך על אזנך   וזולתו ממה שינהג זה המנהג 
>   כן הקל מעט זה החכם בזה המספר  להוציא ממנו אלו המוסרים הנפלאים שיצאו
>   מאלו המספרים  כאילו כל אבר ואבר מאברי האדם  יאמר   עשה בי מצוה  וכל
>   יום ויום מימות השנה השמשית אומר   אל תעבור בי עבירה
>
> ובהיות הענין כן  הוא מבואר שאם היה מספר המצוות מסכים לזה המספר
>   בקירוב    די  בו להוציא ממנו זה המוסר  ולא יצטרך להסכים לו בלי פחת
>   ובלי יתר  הלא תראה כי גם במקומות אשר לא ידובר בהם על צד הדרש  לא
>   ידקדקו החכמים אם יהיה במספר קצת קירוב   כבר תמצא זה מבואר בראשון מסוכה
>   גבי סוכה העשויה ככבשן  שאמרו שאם יש בהיקפה כדי לישב בה עשרים וארבעה
>   בני אדם    כשרה  וכשהוקשה להם זה החשבון אמרו   לא דק   וכל שכן בזה
>   המקום שנאמר בו זה המספר על צד הדרש
>
> ועוד  שאף על פי שנֹאמר שרבי שמלאי דקדק באלו המספרים  ונאמר גם כן שכבר
>   כתב עם זה בביאור אי זה מצוות הם אלו אשר מנה  הנה לא יחלוק אחד
>   מהמעיינים שאם יתבאר מדברי התלמוד היות מספרם זולת זה המספר  שכבר יהיו
>   דבריו דברי יחיד  ויהיו בטלים   כאילו תאמר אם יתבאר שכבר מנה מצוה אין
>   ראוי שתמנה לפי שורשי התלמוד והנמשך אליו  או אם לא מנה מה שראוי למנות 
>   וזה ממה שאין ספק באמיתתו  ולזה הוא מבואר שלא ימנענו זה המספר אשר זכר
>   ר׳ שמלאי מהמשך במנין המצוות לפי מה שיראה מחכמת התלמוד

Thus, in sum, the number 613 has very little practical significance. It is useful in teaching us a lesson, but it does not necessarily reflect the true number of mitzvot. There could in actuality be many more than 613 mitzvot (or theoretically many fewer). The only correct way to count mitzvot is to go through the Torah and Talmud and analyze each case individually to determine whether something is a mitzvah or not. Whatever number we have at the end of the entire analysis is the number of mitzvot, and that number can theoretically be anything.

This approach, I believe, resolves all the questions mentioned here:

> [I]t's clear from the Rishonim that there are more than just 613.

This is not an issue because R. Simlai was either being imprecise with the number 613, or his opinion was rejected.

> [T]here would be only 3 mitzvos from Bereishis to Bo.

This has nothing to do with R. Simlai. We have to learn through the Torah and Talmud, and if we find mitzvot between Bereishis and Bo then we count them, and if we don't find mitzvot then we don't count them.

> [T]here would be entire parshiyos (not sidra's) without any mitzvos.

Same as above – we learn through each parsha, and if we find mitzvot then we count them, and if we don't find mitzvot then we don't count them. It is not R. Simlai's fault if the Torah does not say anything that can be construed as a mitzvah in an entire parsha.

Comment: I liked it, but I think the discussion is lame when nobody cares to define "a Mitzvah" first. This always reminds me Rambam Hilchos Kriat Shemah, when he states the Mitzvah Deorayso is to read and no Mitzvah mentioning Yetzias Mizrayim, but then starts the text with "פעמים בכל יום קוראין ק"ש" and then a couple of lines later "ומצוה להזכיר יציאת מצרים ביום ובלילה"ץ  so Rambam is flawed as well with definitions.

Answer (score 0):

One factor that may have an influence on the count of mitzvos is that some mitzvos are included in others.
For example, the ShLO hakadosh writes (I think on Pesachim ) that the  chessed associated mitzvos like hachnosas orchim, bikur cholim, levayas hamess  are included in veholachta bidrochav

Comment: Out of 4 kamatz's in והלכת בדרכיו you transliterated 2 as "a" and 2 as "o". Go figure. In any event I don't see how this address the question at all. Did you mean for this to be a comment.