# What's the practical difference between Mitzva Diorisas that Are listed as one of the 613; And those Not listed as one of the 613?

Tags: halacha, rambam, mitzvah, sefer-hachinuch

What's the (general) practical Difference between one of the **613 Mitzvahs** ,counted by the ***Monay Hamotzvos***,whether its an Asay or Lo-Tasay and an (Asay or Lo-Tasay) that isn't part of the 613 Mitzvahs?

Surely, with the harsh Machlokisim, and (esp. The Rambam's ingenious calculations and the fact that he felt it necessary to correct one of the Gaonim based on that establishing his 14 Rules) There are differences both quality and quantitatively.

But what are they?

Comment: Can you give an example of a biblical command not counted in the 613? I didn't think there were any.

Comment: [Perhaps nothing?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59977/only-613-commandments-cant-be/95024#95024)

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not sure I'm following your question. Let's say the Bahag and Rambam argue if mitzvos that weren't said ledoros make the list or not. What would be the practical difference if they make the list or not? Does anything change if the mitzvah of [writing the torah on large stones](https://thetaryag.com/bahag/611) is in taryag, or no? Everyone agrees the Jews were commanded to do it, but the Rambam holds it's not in the list, and Bahag apparently disagrees.